# The History of Project Management

Tags: methodology, education, culture, waterfall, lean

There are many styles of Project Management, and many Project Management philosophies to choose from. Some emphasise a plan-based approach, some try to tackle emerging objectives in a dynamic or adaptive way, some emphasise structure and documentation, and others emphasise people. There is Lean management, PMBOK, critical path, the process approach, and so on – but where did the different styles and directions of Project Management originate and how has the discipline evolved until today?

Answers should

- summarise the historical origins of Project Management,
- provide references and links for further information,
- highlight the most important characteristics of each approach to Project Management,
- show who, where and in what context the approach was created (explain how people came to that approach and what problems they were trying to solve with it), and
- give some indication of the role of each approach in today's Project Management activities.

Since multiple historical lines of development exist, a valuable answer should give some categorisation that allows comparison of differences and similarities in different Project Management approaches.

Comment: Is it a question or you want the members of this forum to write some parts of an elaborate for you ;-)?

Comment: This question doesn't really fit what this site is about. This is a Q&A site to answer questions about specific *problems* you come across in your work. Stack Exchange isn't really designed for these types of chatty, open-ended discussions. If you have a question which falls within the guidelines of our [**FAQ**](http://pm.stackexchange.com/faq), please feel free to try again.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that [Wikipedia article on project management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_management) along with other interlinked articles (if you need more detail) answer your question very well.